# Java - Taking certain pieces of info from a .dat file and putting it into a .idx file

Tags: java

I am writing some code to create and run 18000 tests every minute for 24 hours and store the results in a `.dat` file which I can do.

My next task was at the start of every hour to take a timestamp, device id and random test id and store it in a `.idx` file, so it will only have 24 lines of data.

I am having trouble with it. I can get it to print results at the start of every hour but it will also print up results for each test while I only want it to take a random test at the start of every hour.

Here is what I have done so far;

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{ 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();

    File fileNameDat = new File(df.format(date) + ".dat");
    File fileNameIdx = new File(df.format(date) + ".idx");

    RandomAccessFile rafDat = new RandomAccessFile(fileNameDat, "rw");
    RandomAccessFile rafIdx = new RandomAccessFile(fileNameIdx, "rw");
    Random rand = new Random();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

    try
    {
        for(int hours = 0; hours < 24; hours++)
        {   
            for(int tests = 1; tests <= 10; tests++)        //18000 tests in total
            {   
                for(int mins = 0; mins < 60; mins++)
                {   
                    rafDat.writeLong(cal.getTimeInMillis() + mins * 60000);     //Timestamp 
                    rafDat.writeInt(283);                                       //Device ID
                    rafDat.writeInt(tests);                                     //Test ID
                    rafDat.write((byte)1);                                      //Availability
                    rafDat.writeInt(rand.nextInt(500));                         //Latency           
                }

                if(cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0 && tests <= 2)
                {
                    rafIdx.writeLong(cal.getTimeInMillis());
                    rafIdx.writeInt(0);
                    rafIdx.writeInt(rand.nextInt(tests));
                }
            }
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
        }
        rafDat.close();
        rafIdx.close();
    } 
    catch(IOException iOE) 
    {
        System.err.println(iOE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

you make sure that cal has no millisecs, no seconds and no minutes, so that

```
cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0
```

is always true. This has the effect that for test 1 and 2, something is written to rafIdx:

```
if(cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) == 0 && cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0 && tests <= 2)
{
    rafIdx.writeLong(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    rafIdx.writeInt(0);
    rafIdx.writeInt(rand.nextInt(tests));
}
```

Your `cal` object is only updated every iteration of the *hours loop*, and then only the hour is updated, keeping the condition valid and explaining your results.

It's not really clear to me where to start rewriting your code to achieve what you want, but perhaps the simplest option is to add a second to your `cal` object every iteration of the *seconds loop*. To make this method match your description of it, you should also build in a mechanism to ensure that exactly one seconds passes every iteration of the *seconds loop*.

Comment: everything in the code bar the `if statement` allows the .dat file to be created just the way I want it to. But i need to grab data at the start of every hour but the test_id will always be 0 as this is always the first test in the first minute of that hour. So what I was hoping for was to to randomly take a test out of the first minute, as it will still be within the hour and display it, hence the random object